# Unable to connect to libvirt qemu+ssh

Tags: ssh, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

First I installed KVM and Qemu on local machine to do some testing. Now I wanted to do so on a remote productive system. I can connect to the productive system from my laptop but not from local machine to remote productive system.
The error message is:

```
Unable to connect to libvirt qemu+ssh://UserName@IpOfServer:Port/system.

Cannot recv data: Der Wert ist zu groß für den definierten Datentyp

Verify that the 'libvirtd' daemon is running on the remote host.

Libvirt URI is: qemu+ssh://UserName@IpOfServer:Port/system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1036, in _do_open
    self._backend.open(self._do_creds_password)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 144, in open
    open_flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 105, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: Cannot recv data: Der Wert ist zu groß für den definierten Datentyp
```

I can login from local system via ssh to remote system,

```
libvirt-bin libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon  libvirt-daemon-system
```

is installed and my user is added to libvirt group but I can't get it to work.

Comment: The solution is the same,but the error message is another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same error like here: 
[Unable to connect to libvirt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116898/unable-to-connect-to-libvirt-xubuntu)

I didn't see the correlation between the two different errors.